# Finite, countably infinite and uncountable sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble deciding if these equation are finite, countably infinite and uncountable.

- $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$ is **countable**
- $\{ 2^n \;\vert\; n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is **finite**
- $\{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \;\vert\; a \neq b \}$ is **countable**
- $ \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is **uncountable** (where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of the rational numbers)
- $\mathbb{Z}$ is **uncountable** (where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integer numbers)
- The cardinality of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is $\aleph_0$
- $ \{ 2a \;\vert\; a \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is **countably infinite** (where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integer numbers)
- $ \mathbb{Q}^- \cup \mathbb{Z}^- \cup \{ 1, 2, 3 \} $ is **countable**

Is there anyone who can confirm if I have understod the meaning of finite, countably infinite and uncountable correctly?

Comment: Several of these are incorrect. Can you tell us what you think the definitions of finite, countably infinite, and uncountable are?

Comment: As i understand is that something is finite when a set has cardinality of x_0 or is a element. Countably infinite is when a set only has cardinality of x_0 and uncountable is when a set is not countable.

Comment: @Tom: I’m guessing that by $x_0$ you mean $\aleph_0$. If so, your definition of *finite* is incorrect: a set if finite if its cardinality is less than $\aleph_0$, countable if its cardinality is $\le\aleph_0$, countably infinite if its cardinality is $\aleph_0$, and uncountable if its cardinality is $>\aleph_0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So that means the first, second and the sixth are correct? Can you tell me witch one i have correct. I think that will help me understanding.

Comment: Hi @Tom, welcome to the forum! I have made some edits to your question. Using MathJax is recommended for writing mathematics, so make sure to click "edit" below your question and have a look at the code there as a first example if you're not familiar with it. It is fairly straightforward if you already know some LaTeX.

Comment: @wheepy thanks alot, will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $S$ is *finite* if the cardinality of the set (the number of elements in the set), denoted $|S|\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Example:**
A set you gave was $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, and clearly $|S| = 5\in\mathbb{N}$ so it is finite.

---

A set is *countable* if you can form a bijection (one-to-one correspondence) between the elements of the set and a subset of the natural numbers. In other words, you can enumerate elements in the set.

**Example 1**: If we again consider $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, this itself is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ so by definition it is countable.

**Example 2**: Whilst your example of $S = \{2^n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not actually finite (try to see why that is based on the definition), it is countable. This is easy to see as for any $n$, it maps to $2^n$, so there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb{N}$ and $S$.

**Example 3**: A cartesian product of finitely many countable sets is countable. $\mathbb{Q}$ is actually countable - there are clever ways to enumerate the rationals (perhaps think about this yourself or look up some examples), so your example of $S=\mathbb{Q}^3$ is actually countable.

Sidenote: We usually define the size of the set of natural numbers, $|\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$

---

For a set $S$ to be *uncountable*, a few different criteria (but there are more):

- There is not a bijection from $S$ to $\mathbb{N}$
- $|S| > |\mathbb{N}|=\aleph_0$
- If $S$ contains a subset which is itself uncountable

**Example 1:** $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, but $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

**Example 2:** $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$, so $\mathbb{C}$ is also uncountable since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

---

**Exercise:** Try and convince yourself / prove for yourself that $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable (but not finite).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer for my question as it helped me alot understanding the difference between finite, countably infinite and uncountable